# Is Ubuntu or Xubuntu running?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xfce

I had installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Then I installed the following package:

xubuntu-desktop

At the log-in screen I have the options **Ubuntu**, **Xfce session** or **Xubuntu session**.

**Please tell me which operating system is running (Ubuntu or Xubuntu) if I select Xfce session.**

Comment: It will be Ubuntu with xubuntu-desktop. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As you probably know, Ubuntu (as most Linux distributions) are made up out of many packages. When you install a distribution, not every package available is installed, but a certain selection of packages.

The different "flavours" of Ubuntu (Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu and others) basically differ in what that initial selection of packages contains. Ubuntu by default installs for example the Gnome Shell desktop environment, Kubuntu installs the KDE desktop environment and so forth.

But once you've installed the distribution, you can basically "mix and match" like you did when you installed the `xubuntu-desktop` package. Now, your system offers you multiple desktop environments or window managers to choose from when you log in.

As for what your system technically is, it's an Ubuntu system with some additional packages installed that would by default be installed on a Xubuntu system. What exactly to call that is in the eyes of the beholder ;)

Comment: As I could also select "Xubuntu session" at the log-in screen, do I now have installed Xubuntu, too?

Comment: @user773232 Xubuntu and Ubuntu are the same OS, but with different packages.

Comment: I try to make it more clear: If I would like to post a question on askubuntu.com in future regarding my system, do I post that I have a question on Ubuntu or Xubuntu? Maybe that is important for getting a precise answer!

Comment: Would mention that you are using Ubuntu version, plus with desktop.  Some cases it won't matter, unless problem with desktop.  Would be careful with mixing too much, some desktops don't play nice together.

Comment: The only reason why I installed Xfce (xubuntu-desktop) was that I have noticed that my RAM (memory) is getting too little for the default Ubuntu software and I have read that Xfce needs fewer ressources!

Comment: @user773232 Maybe I didn't make my point clear enough: Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Studio and all the other flavours are _the same operating system_. The only thing that's different between them is which selection of packages is installed initially. 

When you've installed your system, the set of packages that's been definied for Ubuntu has been installed. Later, you added a package that _would_ have been installed automatically if you had installed Xubuntu. That doesn't magically change your system's identity, and the exact demonination doesn't matter too much, anyway.

Comment: @user773232 As for tagging future questions, in many cases there will probably no need to differentiate in this regard. If you've got a question concerning Xfce, tag it `xfce`. If you've got a question concerning an usb device, tag it `usb`, and so on. Only a very small subset of questions, if any at all, will need the information whether it's Ubuntu or Xubuntu or Ubuntu MATE or what have you.